# Why set equality breaks here?

Tags: python, set, spacy

I have a function `f` that is defined like below:

```
def f(doc):
    return filter(lambda ent: ..., doc.ents)
```

`doc` is a Spacy document object and `doc.ents` returns a generator object. There's also `doc.noun_chunks` that returns a generator object. Something weird happens however:

```
>>> a = list(f(doc))
[Apple, Banana]

>>> b = list(doc.noun_chunks)
[Banana, Apple]

>>> a[0] == b[1]
True

>>> a[1] == b[0]
True

>>> set(a) == set(b)
False

>>> list(set(a))[0] == list(set(b))[1]
True

>>> list(set(a))[1] == list(set(b))[0]
True

>>> set(list(set(a))) == set(list(set(b)))
False
```

Why the set equality doesn't work here?!

P.S. I'm writing an app for a client using Spacy, so unfortunately can't paste the complete code here and also faked the names "f", "Apple" and "Banana"... but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Can you simplify your example?

Comment: @AlexYu Basically the example says I have two list of two elements. Their corresponding elements are equal to each other. But the lists themselves are not because of ordering. However the sets of those lists are not equal (why could that be?).

The later part is to show the equality of the initial list elements remains invariant across iterative applications of `list(set(list(set(...`.

Comment: `(set(a) == set(b)) == False` and no other manipulations with conversion to lists cannot make inequal sets equal. What's wrong in your opinion?

Comment: can you reproduce that with pure list of strings (drop the spacy part that we cannot reproduce)

Comment: no need to convert to a set, compare sorted lists.

Comment: This looks like it may actually be a spaCy bug. The `Token.__hash__` implementation seems to be inconsistent with its rich comparison method.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No. I can't replicate it with pure strings. It only happens in the code involving Spacy code. And also comparing sorted lists works fine.
My curiosity however is there because Spacy code doesn't change the definition of __eq__ on the sets globally so why they don't work?!

Comment: @user2357112 That makes sense!
Edit: You're right! hash(a[0]) != hash(b[1])

Comment: "user2357112" and "That makes sense" are often found in the same sentence.

Comment: @user2357112  Do you mean https://github.com/explosion/spacy/blob/master/spacy/tokens/token.pyx ? What's wrong with `Token.__hash__` ?

Comment: @AlexYu: `Token.__hash__` is using `self.i`, while the rich comparison routine is comparing `self.idx` against `other.idx`. I don't know enough about spaCy to know whether that should produce consistent results, but it's a definite red flag, and the results of Atonal's manual hash comparison indicate an inconsistency.